# Control the getter/setter method names for properties of type object

Tags: java, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

For the below json, the jsonschema2pojo utility/plugin generates the getter-setter methods by suffixing JavaName of object in **user.json** with 'get'/'set' respectively.

**Example:** if the 'JavaName' in user.json is **User**, then getter/setter for property loggedInUser would take the name **getUser()** and **setUser(User user)**. How can I avoid it taking $ref json's java name but instead user the property name like to generate methods like **getLoggedInUser()** and **setLoggedInUser(User user)**?

```
{
   "type" : "object",
   "properties" : {
      "loggedInUser" : {
          "$ref" : "user.json"
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have tagged this question for Java and my question contains "Java" which should be enough to convey that information. Please be reasonable in downvoting a question. If you have an idea try to help else just don't proofread to downvote please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
javaName
javatype
```

https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference#user-content-javaname

https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference#user-content-javatype